# Std::vector<bool> <=> Qvariant

Tags: c++, qt

How can I cast from `vector<>` to `QVariant` and vice versa?

I tried to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(vector<bool>)` but it doesn't cast correctly when I do:

```cpp
QVariant v; 
std::vector<bool> vec;
v.setValue<std::vector<bool>>(vec);
```

Comment: Vector or QVector or std::vector?

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<bool>` is such a weirdo that it got its own section in the Standard and [documentation  page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Make certain its really what you want  and not a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: I need a cast from std::vector<bool> to Qvariant for model->setData() function and vice versa to pass the vector to my obj into the model. Then when I will finish coding I have to implement my custom vector (for accademic reasons)

Comment: You don't need to explicitly specify the type when calling `setValue()`, the type will be deduced from the input parameter: `v.setValue(vec);`

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't cast correctly"? Also why not put the `std::` in Q_DECLARE_METATYPE?

Comment: I would have put my std::vector inside a class like "MeshData" which inherit QObject and is accessible in qml. maybe you will have transform to store in the futur or child element ...